# Subir una foto tomada con la cámara web a una base de datos MySQL php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html5

Quiero saber, ¿cómo puedo tomar una imagen tomada con la cámara web de la laptop, almacenada en canvas y subirla a mi base de datos?
Les dejo el código. Puse un input con `method="post"` `action="datbase.php"` porque estaba intentando lo de la base de datos con php.

Gracias de antemano.

```js
function activateCamera() {

 var video = document.querySelector("#camaraOn");
 navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMEdia;
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
    }
    function handleVideo(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }
    function videoError(e) {
        alert("La camara No esta funcionando Permita el acceso")
    }
}


//Funcion para capturar el streaming
function tomarFoto() {

     var video = document.querySelector("#camaraOn");
   canvas=document.getElementById("fotoTomada");
   let {left,top}= video.getBoundingClientRect();

     canvas.width=1080;
     canvas.height=650;

     canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video,0,0,1080,650);
   canvas.style.left=`${left}px`;
   canvas.style.top=`${top}px`;
   canvas.style.position="absolute";
   canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   fotAux=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   input= document.getElementById("urlImg");
   input.value=fotAux;

   canvas.style.visibility="visible";
   btnGuard= document.getElementById("btnGuard");
   btnGuard.style.visibility="visible";

   btnFotoTomada= document.getElementById("btnTake");
   btnFotoTomada.style.visibility="hidden";
   btnFotoTomada.disabled=true;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> SnapDCU </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/kickstart.js"></script> <!-- KICKSTART -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kickstart.css" media="all" /> <!-- KICKSTART -->
    <script src="js/script.js"> </script>

  </head>
  <header>

    <nav class="navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">SnapWebDCU</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
        <li> <a href="klk.php">Fotos</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    </nav>

  </header>

  <body onload="activateCamera()">
    <style>
    .canvasCamara{
      position: relative;
    }
    .canvasCamara>.botonesAccion{
      background: url('css/img/shotpng.png') bottom center no-repeat;
       height: 145px;
       left: 50%;
       margin: -64px 0 0 -64px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 85%;
       border: 15px solid transparent;
       width: 145px;
       z-index: 1;
    }



    .canvasCamara>.btnGuard{
      visibility: hidden;
      background: url('css/img/derecha.png') bottom right no-repeat;
       height: 145px;
       left: 50%;
       margin: -64px 0 0 -64px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 85%;
       border: 15px solid transparent;
       width: 145px;
       z-index: 1;

    }




    </style>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="canvasCamara">
        <video autoplay="true" width="1080" id="camaraOn" height="650"> </video>
        <button class="botonesAccion" onclick="tomarFoto()" type="button" id="btnTake" name="btnTake"></button>
      </div>

      <div class="divCanv">
            <canvas id="fotoTomada" height="1" width="1" ></canvas>

            <form class="btnGuard" method="post" action="database.php">
              <input type="text" id="urlImg" name="urlImg"/>
                <button id="btnGuard" type="submit"   name="btnGuard"></button>
            </form>


      </div>





    </div>

  </body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando tomas una foto lo haces con canvas, pintando en el método [`Context#drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) el elemento `video` en donde se reproduce el `MediaStream`. Una vez que se ha pintado el cuadro en el instante en que llamas a `drawImage`, el canvas está disponible para obtener una URL.

```
let photo = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

El método [`Canvas#toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) regresa una URL data; este tipo de URLs sirven para "camuflar" pequeños archivos en una URL; en caso pases un mime correspondiente a una imagen, este método retornará la imagen en formato **base64**

Guardar dicha imagen en una base de datos MySQL se puede hacer de distintas formas, cada una de ellas corresponde a **cómo está definida la tabla** en la base de datos.

---

#### Columna `Text`/`Varchar`

En caso la columna esté definida como `Text` o `Varchar` o cualquier otra columna que te permita insertar texto, puedes almacenar directamente la imagen en formato base64.

```
INSERT INTO photos(data) VALUES($b64_photo);
```

#### Columna `Blob`

En caso la columna sea `Blob` o derivadas como `LongBlob`, primero se necesita convertir la imagen en base64 a un objeto binario. Esto puedes hacerlo tanto en el cliente como en el servidor.

**Convertir base64 a File**

Para convertir una imagen codificada en base64 a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/File), primero es necesario crear un objeto [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Blob) a partir de ella. Sin embargo, el constructor de `File` **no está soportado en IE11 ni Edge**.

El mismo fin puedes lograr convertiendo el base64 a un blob mediante un [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Uint8Array). Este tipo de dato almacena **enteros sin signo** de 8 bits.

```
function dataURI2Blob(uri) {
  let [ info, encoded ] = photo.split(',');
  let mime = info.match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
  let bstr = atob(encoded);
  let data = new Uint8Array(bstr.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < bstr.length; i++) {
    data[i] = bstr.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  return new Blob([data] { type: mime });
}
```

La función anterior solo recorre el string en bytes del base64 y obtiene por cada letra **su representación Unicode**, luego la agrega al array. Finalmente, le pasa el array a `Blob` indicando su respectivo mime type.

---

En este punto, lo único que tienes que hacer es enviar el `Blob` por AJAX mediante un `FormData`:

> **Nota:** el siguiente ejemplo usa la nueva API para peticiones AJAX en JavaScript. En caso no uses el [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch), hazlo por medio de [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest) o por jQuery.

```
let photo = canvas.toDataURI('image/png');
let data = new FormData();

data.append('photo', dataURI2Blob(photo);

fetch ('/endpoint', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
)
.then(res => res.text())
.then(res => alert(res));
```

En PHP, escribe la imagen en un directorio temporal, luego léela y la insertas en la base de datos.

```
$img = fopen($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
$stmt->bind_param("b", $null);
$stmt->send_long_data(0, $img);
$stmt->execute();

echo "Tu foto ha sido subida";
```

Comment: Excelente. Me funciono correctamente. Gracias!